# Infinite vertical carousel in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, carousel, vertical-scrolling

I'm looking to make an infinite vertical carousel in Jetpack Compose but I can't find how to do it.
I want something like this.

I did not find an example on the internet in Compose, everything is in XML.
I try https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/ but it's not exactly what I want.

Thanks for helping me.[image]

Comment: And what is exactly that you want?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

It depends, you can use Pager Accompanist library:

https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/pager

And you can check the docs here:

https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/

**Solution 2:**

You can also try:

```
@Composable
fun CircularList(
    items: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)

  LazyColumn(state = listState, modifier = modifier) {
      items(
          count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
          itemContent = {
              // your content
          }
      )
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried that, not exactly what I'm looking for.
I want an infinite list and I want the exact animation of the GIF in my question.
I don't think there are existing libraries like in XML, I'll try to do it all in code.

Comment: Check the second solution if it is of a better help.